# gwt server side to client side

Tags: gwt, rpc, messagebox

my program can use "fireEvent" in client side, then async Callback.

But how to directly call from server side to client side function like "MessageBox" if server execute somethings wrong / error? (Showing a messageBox that error message)

Server side:
    ABC.java

```
try {

//SFTP coding

} catch (JSchException e) {
System.err.println("Time out for connecting SFTP server");

//What should i put here to call MessageBoxHandler
//MessageBoxHandler(String a, String b);
//cannot call client side function in server side...
}
```

Client side:

```
public class MessageBoxHandler {

public MessageBoxHandler(String a, String b) {

    MessageBox.alert(a, b,
            new Listener<MessageBoxEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handleEvent(MessageBoxEvent be) {
                    if (be.getButtonClicked().getItemId()
                            .equals(Dialog.OK)) {

                    //may be a action should be here , nvm
                    //i just want to show messageBox only

                    }
                }
            });

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are doing, but I don't think this is the good approach. What you should do is use RPC (because that's what you're obviously using), and instead of just catching the exception on server side and logging the error, you should throw the exception in you server side method to get it in the `onFailure` method on client side RPC callback.

You should check [this tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) under the *_Handling Excpetions* section.